# Div click doesn't behave as a mouse click

Tags: javascript

In this [website](https://www.yad2.co.il/realestate/rent?topArea=2&area=1&city=5000&neighborhood=195&propertyGroup=apartments,houses,misc&property=1,11,25,3,30,32,33,39,4,41,44,45,49,5,50,51,55,6,61,7&rooms=3--1&price=-1-9100&open-item-id=b6ck53mz&is-kones=false&view=image-gallery) there are two tabs, if I click on any one of them the tab opens, but when I get the document with javascript and use `.click()` function it does nothing.
I tried also the `dispatchEvent` function but it didn't work (actually I don't know which event I should put there).
I'm looking for an explanation, how can I figure the answer myself, i.e. how can I know how does the website get my mouse click event?

the code I tried: `document.getElementsByClassName("feeditem table")[0].click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div you are selected is not the one that has an event bound to it. However, the child, `.feed_item`, does listen to a `click` event.

The snippet below will get you the first `.feed_item` in the list and clicks it.

```
const item = document.querySelector('.feed_item');
item.click();
```

The feed items also have id's, so you can target the specifically with an id selector using the same `querySelector` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`getEventListeners(element)`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#getEventListeners-function).

> `getEventListeners(object)` returns the event listeners registered on the specified object. The return value is an object that contains an array for each registered event type (`click` or `keydown`, for example). The members of each array are objects that describe the listener registered for each type.